# Any way to use Spring @Value annotations for non-singleton beans?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, annotations

Currently I use the following method to inject properties into beans:

app.properties:

```
SingletonBean.valueA=this is a value
```

spring.xml:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:app.properties"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="..."/>
```

SingletonBean.java:

```
@Component
public class SingletonBean {
    @Value("${SingletonBean.valueA}")
    private String valueA;
}
```

This works great and is extremely convenient to be able to keep all my configs in a single, simple properties file. Is there any way I could extend this to work with multiple Beans of the same class? I need to do the following, with the 2 beans having different properties:

```
@Autowired private SampleBean beanA;
@Autowired private SampleBean beanB;
```

I know I can use the `@Qualifier(name=...)` annotation to support the following xml:

```
<bean id="beanA" class="SampleBean">
    <property name="key1" value="A1"/>
    <property name="key2" value="A2"/>
</bean>
<bean id="beanB" class="SampleBean">
    <property name="key1" value="B1"/>
    <property name="key2" value="B2"/>
</bean>
```

But with this I am forced to use old style setters in my `SampleBean` class, where I would prefer to use the newer `@Value` annotations.

Anyone know of a way to accomplish what I want that remains most consistent with how I am currently injecting my other beans?

The simple solution is just to inject all of the properties into the bean that utilizes the 2 `SampleBean` instances and create them with `new` instead. In my real code however there are actually 3 instances, each with 15 or so properties. This is much more cruft and repetition than I would like.

Comment: What spring version are we talking about?

Comment: It's a bit weird that you want to stick to xml config but want to avoid "old style setters". Because it's perfectly solvable using setters, and setters are far from "old style", mate ;).

Comment: @msparer how would you answer this with Java Config? I say old style setters but really I just hate the boilerplate. `@Value` annotations are so much more concise

Comment: @fateddy 3.1 but I can upgrade if a better solution is present in newer releases

Comment: @thedarklord47 was thinking about `@ConfigurationProperties` (see here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties). But then again, I'm not sure if a) it helps in your case and if b) upgrading it's worth the effort (requires spring-boot). your call.

Comment: could you demonstrate how this could be accomplished with `ConfigurationProperties`? It still appears to be class level, rather than Bean level

Comment: @thedarklord47 actually you are right. What @ConfigurationProperties does is mapping properties with a certain prefix onto a bean. But that requires a java config based approach. What could work in your case is to implement a custom `BeanPostProcessor`, which mimics a similar functionality (mapping by convention). Then you wouldn't need `@Value` annotations anymore. If you would like, I could outline how that could look like.